# How to define variable that's a word in if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to learn if statements and want to create a program that can calculate an area of either a circle or a rectangle but the error keeps popping up definite 'rectangle'/'circle'. I tried a few ways but nothing is working.

I tried quotes and separate variable definition

```
import math
choice = input("Please enter rectangle or circle")
if 'rectangle' == choice:

    length = input("Please enter length in cm")
    width = input("Please enter width in cm")
    Area = int(length) * int(width)
    print("The area of the square is", Area)
elif choice == 'circle':

    diameter = input("Please enter diameter in cm")
    radius = int(diameter) / 2
    Area = math.pi * (radius ** 2)
    print("The area of the circle is", Area)
```

I want to be able to choose the shape and calculate the area

Comment: What's wrong? Your code seems working fine.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x? What's the actual error?

Comment: no Python 3, I can't get past the first line. It just doesn't do anything else

Comment: Add `else: print("Invalid choice: {!r}".format(choice))` to see what your input *is*, that it didn't compare equal to any of the expected inputs.

Comment: There seems to be no problem with your code. It runs fine. Maybe a typo in your input. In this case you can add another `else`case and `print`an error message in case the input is something other than rectangle or circle

Comment: I added else case and error message and now that's a response to everything even if i write 'circle or 'rectangle'. It's like it isn't recognising the those words. Do you know why that may be?

Answer (score 0):

Only problem I can think of is that you must be using extra space after inputting the shape. E.g: "rectangle " instead of "rectangle".

try using choice.strip() in if statement instead of choice to compare it with string.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried using choice.strip() and now no matter if I type rectangle or circle, it goes down the rectangle route. Any idea why?

Comment: u must have changed something else too.....can u show/tell what other changes u have made.